# Paypal Response getting "Fail"

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am integrating paypal to my shopping cart
Here is my Value transfer Form

```
      <h3>By Paypal</h3><hr/>
       <label>Click Here</label>
       <br/>
     <?php
      include 'controller/connection.php';
      $paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      $paypal_id = 'my-sellerID_biz@yahoo.com';                                                                                                                                $cancel_url = 'http://my-website/index.php?action=cancel';
      $return_url = 'http://my-website/store.php';
      $i = 0;
      $products = array();
      $qry = mysql_query("select * from temp_cart where tokenId='$token'");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
      $pid = $row[0];
      $pname = $row[1];
      $qty = $row[3];
      $price = $row[4];
      $amount = $row[5];
      $products[] = array('pid' => $pid, 'pname' => $pname, 'qty' => $qty, 'price' => $price, 'amount' => $amount);
       }
    ?>
     <form action="<?php echo $paypal_url;?>" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id;?>">
             <?php
             foreach ($products as $product) {
             $i++;
              //echo $product['amount'];
              ?>
             <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $product['pname']?>">
             <input type='hidden' name='item_number_<?php echo $i;?>' value='<?php echo $product['pid'] ?>' />

             <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $product['amount']?>">
            <?php
              }
             ?>

        <input type='image' src='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif' name='submit' style='display:{$display_button}' />
   </form>
```

This is working correctly.
But after payment when i redirect from paypal i get FAIL response.But in my send box account it shows me COMPLETE.And showing me CART. My code for getting Response from paypal is :-

```
<?php
session_start();

//include('connection.php');
/*
 update: 06/27/2011
  - updated to use cURL for better security, assumes PHP version 5.3
*/

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];

$pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; 

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "MY API TOKEN";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$res){
    //HTTP ERROR
}else{
     // parse the data
    $lines = explode("\n", $res);
    $keyarray = array();
    echo $lines[0];

    echo "<br>";
    if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
       echo $lines[0];
        for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
        list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
        $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
    }
    //echo "skjdhckh";
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct




    $user_email = 'myID@gmail.com';

     $site_name = 'Company name';
     $eol = "\r\n";
     $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol;
     $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . $eol;
     $headers .= 'From:' . $site_name . ' <mailID@gmail.com>'. $eol;
     $headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $site_name . ' <mailID@gmail.com>' . $eol;
     $headers .= 'Return-Path:' . $site_name . ' <mailID@gmail.com>' . $eol;

     $eol = "\r\n<br />";
     $thanks_text = $eol.$eol.'Thanks!'. $eol;
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && ($_SESSION['token']))
        {
                include('connection.php');

                $user=$_SESSION['user'];
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                $token=$_SESSION['token'];
                $_SESSION['token']=$token;
                //$sub=$_SESSION['coursename'];
                date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne'); 
                $date = date('y-m-d h:i:s a', time());
                $qry="update allorder set status='completed',date='$date'  where token='$token' and name1='$user'";
                $run_qry=mysql_query($qry);

                    if($run_qry)
                    {

    /*$select_id="select email from register where username='$username'";
    $run_qry2=mysql_query($select_id);
     if($row=mysql_fetch_row($run_qry2))
    {   */
      $email=$row[0];   
      $email_tpl = 'Hello Buyer,' . $eol;
      $email_tpl .= "We have received your payment of $amount $cc." . $eol;
      $email_tpl .= "Thanks for the purchase." . $eol;
      $email_tpl .= $eol . $thanks_text;

    mail ($email, 'Payment Received', $email_tpl, $headers);
    echo $email;
    $_SESSION['username']=$user;
                ?>
                 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            // Print a message
            alert('Thank you for your purchase! your Payment was successfull. Now You can print and download your certificate');
                // Redirect to some page of the site.
            window.location = 'index.php';
                </script>
                <?php
    //}

                }

                    else
                    {
                    echo mysql_error();
                    }

    }

    }
    else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
       echo 'Transaction Failed';
    }
}

?>
```

Every thing is working correctly but i am getting Fail response.
please Help me if i am forgetting something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you are using your PDT token from your test sandbox seller account, if you are testing with the sandbox.

REASONS FOR FAIL,  4002, or, 4003 RESPONSE

- Make sure you are posting back "tx", "cmd", and Auth values
  For PayPal to return SUCCESS and the transaction details, your PDT script needs to post the "tx" variable pulled from the return string, the Auth token from your account to PayPal using the cmd "_notify-synch".
- Invalid Authentication Token
  Check the token to  make sure is is accurate and is being passed back correctly.  Make sure your  token is a contiguous string and that there are no line breaks in it in your  script. For some languages, this may make a  difference.
- Make sure you are not posting back to the wrong URL.
  If you are testing in the Sandbox, you need to ensure your script posts back to www.sandbox.paypal.com. If you are on the live site, the script should post back to www.paypal.com. You will receive FAIL if you are testing in the Sandbox and your script posts back to the live site (or vice versa)
- Validating the same "tx" over 5 times
  Check user behavior. Another way to get a FAIL is if you reference the same "tx" over 5 times. Example: If a user refreshes the PDT page 5 times after seeing the details, they will see FAIL on the last refresh. This is not an error. This is done on purpose for security, so that the URL that PDT creates cannot be accessed indefinitely to retrieve transaction specific data.
- Invalid or missing "tx" value
  The "tx" value is the transaction ID which is used to gather the Payment information.  If this is invalid or not present you will get a FAIL response as the payment data could not be retrieved.

PDT NOT  RECEIVED

- Email address associated with payment
  For PDT to work, you must confirm the e-mail address used as the value of business in your button code. If this e-mail address is not confirmed, PDT will not work as you will not see the PDT query string appended to your return URL.
- Make sure you are using a correctly formatted return URL.
  When you enable PDT,  the URL you are using as the default Auto Return URL must be a valid hostname or  IP address and not an internal intranet URL or the user will not be  auto-returned back to that URL. Make sure you use a valid URL as the URL of  where you want the user to go back to or you will not see the intended  result.
- Subscriptions  style payment buttons
  PDT is not designed  to work with subscriptions in that, if you have a subscription with a free  trial, you will see no data on the return page/PDT process. This is because PDT  transfers payment data and if at the time of signup, if there is no payment,  then it follows that there is no payment data to  transfer.
- User behavior
  PDT is customer activated through the return method by selecting the return button or by not selecting anything in cases when customers log into their PayPal accounts to pay.  This means the buyer can change the return flow or exit out of the browser and no data is transferred.

Comment: Also, the "tx" param is case-sensitive, and PayPal transaction IDs are all uppercase. If something in your code (or [a PayPal bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30386965/647002)) is lowercasing the tx, you'll get error 4002.

Comment: @medmunds - Wow! Your comment related to the tx field value being case-sensitive just saved me from wasting another week, maybe more, of trying to fix this bug! Unbelievable! TX!!!!!