# Paypal Payment Data Transfer(PDT) Error 4002

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, eclipse-pdt

I'm working on integrating my website with paypal and getting it to work in sandbox mode. I am working in Codeigniter (PHP). I have gotten IPN notifications working perfectly but can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with PDT(need this to show a proper confirmation page and return). I have checked the identity token numerous times, made sure the htaccess file doesn't limit access on the call back, made sure the email is verified for the business field, made sure everything is going to sandbox and not the live site, and made sure auto-return is enabled with the correct paramters, and even asked technical support(without receiving any useful help). But I keep getting a return ($response) of "FAIL" with an error code of 4002. Any help in how to debug this will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my form:

```
<form class="paypal login" action="http://########.com/paypal/purchase" method="post" id="paypal_form">    
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=""> 
        <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_tc_id" value="###########">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="paypal-btn" class="paypal-order" alt="Order" value="Purchase"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is where it goes:

```
$querystring = '?';
$querystring .= "business=".urlencode("paypal@#######.net")."&";
$querystring .= "cmd=".urlencode("_xclick")."&";
$querystring .= "amount=".urlencode(krw_usd($items_no_tax_price))."&";
$querystring .= "rm=".urlencode(2)."&";
$querystring .= "quantity=".urlencode($quant)."&";
$querystring .= "first_name=".urlencode($first_name)."&";
$querystring .= "last_name=".urlencode($last_name)."&";
$querystring .= "email=".urlencode($email)."&";
$querystring .= "currency_code=".urlencode("USD")."&";
$querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
$querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url))."&";
$querystring .= "notify_url=".urlencode(stripslashes($notify_url));

header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
```

And here is the return url:

```
$request = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array
    (
      'cmd' => '_notify-synch',
      'tx' => $tx,
      'at' => '#############################',
    )),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
));

$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($request);

$response = substr($response, 7);
$response = urldecode($response);

preg_match_all('/^([^=\s]++)=(.*+)/m', $response, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$response = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

if(isset($response['charset']) AND strtoupper($response['charset']) !== 'UTF-8')
{
  foreach($response as $key => &$value)
  {
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', $response['charset']);
  }
  $response['charset_original'] = $response['charset'];
  $response['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
}

ksort($response);

foreach($response as $k=>$v)
{
    echo "Key: " . $k . ", Value: " . $v;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem with return url and paypal cannot return back after payment and gives you 4002(Internal Error). Please be sure that you can reach return url that you have specified

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the return url is definitely reachable because the redirect goes there perfectly.  And the IPN notification has no problem getting to its page which has a similar route with the same settings.

Answer (score 6):

$tx_token = strtoupper($_GET['tx']),  it`s work.

Comment: It's unclear what you're suggesting that the OP should do. Are you saying that converting the transaction ID to uppercase before sending it to PayPal should fix their problem? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: yes ,  convert the transaction ID before sending it

Comment: Wow, this actually seems to be the issue. Around 2015-05-07, we started getting intermittent PDT notify-synch failures with error 4002 -- with code that has been working for a while. I can confirm that `curl --data 'cmd=_notify-synch&tx=abcde12345&at=MyToken' https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` fails but the exact same command with the tx uppercased succeeds (where 'abcde12345' is the tx PayPal provided in the return url and MyToken is our live PayPal token).

Comment: aye, I saw the tx is in uppercase in the return data of paypal notify

Comment: There seems to be a recently-introduced (May 2015) PayPal bug, where PayPal converts *all* of the return-url query params to lowercase -- which may require workarounds in your own PDT code. The bug *only* happens when the user clicks the "click here to return to..." link at the end of the transaction. (If they wait for the auto redirect back to your site, params are the correct case.) I've reported to PayPal; will update after response.

Comment: PayPal tech support has confirmed the bug and escalated to engineering. Some paths through payment lead to incorrectly-lowercased params to your return url. Until they fix it, you need to uppercase the `tx` as suggested here, and also use case-insensitive string compares on any data you verify.

Comment: PayPal tech support just let me know the fix for the accidental lowercased query params is scheduled to go live on July 28, 2015. So if you're seeing error 4002 after that date, it's probably something different.